# Firefox border-radius

Tags: firefox, css

I'm try to use border-radius on a website, but firefox keeps doing this:
[Firefox CSS](http://s16.postimg.org/jo8wpr2wh/firefox.png).
Everything is good except the top left corner.

This is my css for the border-radius:

```
border-radius:10px 0px 0px 0px;
border:1px solid #FFF;
border-bottom:2px solid #000;
width:400px;
```

It works fine on any other browser but not on firefox 24.

Is there a way to fix/work around this with only css?

Comment: What's your problem with the top-left corner? Looks like the browser does, what you tell him. Where is the black background from? The element or its parent?

Comment: @Boldewyn I saw the problem when someone(who deleted his post..) posted a fiddle. The TR had a background. I changed it so now the TD has the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding: the background-clip property:

```
-moz-background-clip: padding;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
```

Comment: My original problem had to do with the background of the TR. But I tried this on chrome what had the same kind of problem and this works for that.